# upgrading libglu1-mesa to its latest version

Tags: unity, mesa

Yesterday I needed to install `freeglut3`, and ubuntu was saying that it needed `libglu1-mesa=8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2` while `8.1~git1206081121.640409~gd~p` was to be installed.

So in order I did `apt-get install --reinstall libglu1-mesa=8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2` and `freeglut3` finally got installed.

when I started ubuntu today, It got me onto Unity 2D. I got from that that what I did yesterday was not wise. Now compiz cannot start properly I suppose.

I don't know if it is going to work, but if I install the version I had yesterday will it switch automatically ? Also, I do not know how to do it, installing the latest version of libglu1-mesa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa` should upgrade it to the latest version currently available in Ubuntu repositories. A reboot (or just relog) after that should, hopefully, restore your machine to its previous state.

Comment: I have already done that and it says `libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.`

Comment: Another option is to `remove` compiz and install again, it should install the correct version. If this doesnt work, you can try by `remove`ing libglu1-mesa as well before installing.